# Can I use array based processing to add additional column(s)? SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, macros

I have a dataset (a) that looks like this:

```
Name                     Value
Cost_1                     28
Cost_2                     22
Unit_1                     Fixed
Unit_2                     C
```

Is it possible to use an array to have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Name                           Cat_1           Cat_2
Cost                             28              22
Unit                            Fixed             C


%let Cat_Count = 2;
data b;
set a;

array category [&Cat_Count] cat_1-cat_&Cat_count;
.
.
.
run;
```

Not sure how to execute this...the macro variable cat_count will be dynamic.

Comment: You will need to make two passes thru the data.  One to figure out what value you should use for CAT_COUNT macro variable and the second to actually do the transformation.

Comment: Your output looks oriented the wrong direction.  You have numbers and character strings in the CAT_1 variable.  It would be better to make a variable named COST that has numbers and a variable named UNIT that has the strings.

Comment: Yes, but you need to know the maximum amount of columns ahead of time. https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/modules/reshaping-data-long-to-wide-using-the-data-step/ You will need to manipulate your data anyways to fix the name so you're making two passes anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array's but a transpose is more efficient.
First create a new column that separates name into the name and count and then use a proc transpose.

```
data have;
input Name $                    Value $;
cards;
Cost_1                     28
Cost_2                     22
Unit_1                     Fixed
Unit_2                     C
;;;;

run;

data have_cat;
set have;
cat = input(scan(name, 2, "_"), 8.); *numeric conversion not required for this approach but for array approach;
name = scan(name, 1, "_");
run;

proc sort data=have_cat;
by name cat value;
run;

proc transpose data=have_cat out=want prefix=cat_;
by name;
id cat;
var value;
run;
```

Array method - requires everything before PROC TRANSPOSE and max_count macro variable.

```
%let Cat_Count = 2;
data want_array;
set have_cat;
by name;
array category(&cat_count) $ cat_1-cat_&cat_count;
retain cat_1-cat_&cat_count;

if first.name then 
call missing(of category (*));

category(cat) = value;

if last.name then output;
run;
```

Comment: thank you! so if I have name "quantity_cost", do I need to adjust the second argument of scan? or rename it?

Comment: Either approach is a valid option to parse the number/name separately.